# Removing "Word" page numbers in Pages 5

Tags: ms-office, pages, import

I have a document that was imported from Word into Pages a while back, it auto imported page numbers that are somehow magically not selectable.  They are not in the main body and not in the footer.  I have found an article on how to remove them in Pages 4 here: https://discussions.apple.com/thread/5513360?start=0&tstart=0 how do I do the same thing in Pages 5?

Answer (score 1):

I have not come across that problem; however, if you are unable select the page numbers, you could do a select-all and copy/paste the text into a new document.

Comment: Not really an answer to my question.

Comment: My bad, I think I misunderstood the point of the question.

Comment: No it is fine.  Just not a direct answer.  Sometimes there is no answer and ones like you gave here are the best way to go.  If no one has a better solution it may be accepted eventually.

Comment: Would this method move all of the styling across to the new document?

Comment: From what I can tell, yes, it copies all paragraph styles (unless I don't have the font) as well as formats like lists, tables, footnotes and comments. If Pages can read it, it will copy it. The only things I've noticed that are lost are lost when Pages first opens a .docx; background images (which I never use anyway) and bookmarks (which means I have to recreate the ToC).